# Android - overwrite photo in photo library

Tags: android, xamarin.android

In my application I want to give users ability to open, edit and save image from Android photo library. 
Opening is easy, as well as saving as a new file. The problem is with overwriting images (opened from the photo library).

When saving changes I simply overwrite files, knowing the path of the original file.
If user saves a brand new file (not opened from library, but created in the app), the file is saved in 
Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures folder. 
(e.g. /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/img_2019921_212552.jpg)
I generate random file name, append to the directory path, save, and the file is there. 
Knowing this path I can later update file contents by simply overwriting the file.

If however, I open a file from the photo library (including also these files that I had just created with the app), the path that is visible
to me is a kind of weird (e.g. /document/image:87799). I am able to get file contents using this pseudo-code:

```
Android.Net.Uri uri = intent.Data;
Stream stream = ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
```

Upon saving however, the only thing with regard to the photo location that I have is this strange path (e.g. /document/image:87799) 
which of course cannot be used to open write stream to the file.

What I need is:
a way to resolve this strange path into a kind of physical one, which will work with streams (to overwrite file). 
Or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way...? Updating image from photo library seems to be a standard task, which may have a dedicated 
APIs / good practices ?

Comment: "I have is this strange path" -- that is not a path. A `Uri` is not a file. "which of course cannot be used to open write stream to the file" -- I do not use Xamarin, but I would hope that they have an `OpenOutputStream()`, the way the Android SDK does, to go along with `OpenInputStream()`. "a way to resolve this strange path into a kind of physical one" -- you do not have filesystem access to the `Pictures` directory on Android 10 (by default) and Android R and higher (for all apps).

Comment: yes, I'm making the app in Xamarin, but general Android audience may also give valuable hints on this. Solution written in java should be easily translatable into c#

Comment: Yes, there is the OpenOutputStream API. I'll check it and will let know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After my verification, as suggested by CommonsWare: 
The following code can be used to save changed image to photo library.

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(currentPhotoURL);
using (var stream = contentResolver.OpenOutputStream(uri))
{
    await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

What is important, no file system APIs are used here.

Now, as overwriting existing file is solved (knowing the URI of the original image), how can I write a brand new image (byte[] array e.g. with encoded jpeg), without using fileSystem APIs ? (this is what I currently do for 'save as new file' operation). Eventually I will need to have URI to the image (starting with content://) - so as to be able to overwrite that copy, if used decides to overwrite it after a while.